# System hangs frequently

Tags: 12.04, xorg, intel-graphics

### Environment

System spec : Lenovo ideapad U310
Haswell-based Pentium 3556U CPU, 4GB RAM, no discrete graphics. Installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with gnome-fallback session (from official repo)

Repository Using : precise / precise-security / precise-update / precise-backports with main, universe, multiverse, restricted.

3rd party`s repo : Libreoffice/ubuntu for Libreoffice,
                   tualatrix/ubuntu   for Ubuntu Tweak,
                   spotify            for Spotify,
                   tomahawk/ubuntu    for Tomahawk
(No system-related 3rd party package are used)

- xserver-xorg-core version : 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1~precise2,
- xserver-xorg-video-intel version : 2.99.904-0ubuntu2.1~precise1

### Problem

Problem : System totally Hangs very frequently. (I suffered 8+ times during last 24 hours)

When it occur : When I use Firefox (with multiple tabs) and scroll down/up for some page, System hangs. It never occurs on very simple pages (like Linux-related pages or online documents), but It occurs frequently (and randomly) while I`m suffering some pages with pictures, banners, flashes, etc.
Sometimes system stuck on hangs while using (as a foreground) other programs(like Libreoffice), while Firefox have opened already.

I think there are several stages on system hanging.

1) (While I'm browsing with Firefox) Mouse moves, but system does not response. No changes in other windows. (I'm using system-monitor widget for monitoring my system, and If system hangs then updating of widget is stopped) Keyboard sometimes works at that moment. (Not always) So I can use other TTYs by pressing Ctrl + Alt + 1. After move to TTYs, and I usually go back to original gnome session. Then it works **fine**.

I can find some logs in /var/log/syslog :

```
kernel: [  970.227645] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
kernel: [  970.227655] [drm] capturing error event; look for more information in /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_error_state
```

Also there are some related logs on Xorg.0.log (I cannot put anything, since it is quite long) :

```
(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x34) [0x7f50a99cd1e4]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x263) [0x7f50a99ad733]
(EE) 2: /usr/bin/X (0x7f50a9816000+0x6adf4) [0x7f50a9880df4]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f50a2300000+0x5e08) [0x7f50a2305e08]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x7f50a9816000+0x95de7) [0x7f50a98abde7]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7f50a9816000+0xc1627) [0x7f50a98d7627]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f50a8b3c000+0xfcb0) [0x7f50a8b4bcb0]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x7) [0x7f50a787cc67]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (drmIoctl+0x28) [0x7f50a89342e8]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1 (0x7f50a3a2b000+0x60bf) [0x7f50a3a310bf]
```

Also, in this stage, I can push Alt+PrtSc(SysRq) + B (do reboot), and it works fine.

2) If system hangs and I don't do anything for 3~7 seconds, then mouse pointer does not moves anymore, also keyboard won't work too. (Ctrl+Alt+number, SysRq Magic Keys, Ctrl+Alt+Del) At that moment,nothing I can do remains, except for push reset button on my laptop. Also, It usually does not gives any information on logs.

### What I`ve tested

1) Web browser-related

- Removing Adobe flash : Still hangs.
- Removing Addons (like ad blocker) : Still hangs.
- Turing off HW Acceleration : Still hangs.
- Using chrome/chromium : Still hangs.

2) X.org related (http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics)

- Adding i915.semaphores=1 to boot parameter : Still hangs.
- Changing AccelMethod from sna to uxa : Still hangs

3) Other version of Ubuntu

- Ubuntu 14.04 : Still Hangs

4) Connect gdb on xorg (refer towww.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/ServerDebugging and wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing)

- When system hangs, connection of ssh is lost (no input or output) and it is impossible to connect another ssh. So I cannot backtrack anything related to system hang.

I think I tested pretty much, but none is succeed. What I can do it for solving this problem? Is there are more informations or tests required to post bugs on launchpad or xorg bug tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [bug #946899](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/946899) (check */sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_error_state* for details). You could try installing the [Intel 01.org drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) and make sure you are running a recent Linux kernel and your BIOS is the most recent version.